# Passing an 8-bit value to a 1-bit port?

Tags: system-verilog, vivado

I'm using System Verilog. My top-level design file has a 1-bit output `bsOut`. I'm also using a register called `shift_reg`, which outputs an 8-bit number from the port `dOut`. I want to do this:

```
module FinalTop (
    input clk,
    output bsOut
    );
Shift_Reg shift_reg(.clk(clk), .dOut(bsOut));
```

I believe that Vivado/Basys3 will truncate `dOut` by using only the LSB --> `bsOut`, but what if I want to specify a different bit? For example, what if I want to send `.dOut[7](bsOut)`? Obviously this won't work (I tried), but I don't know how to do it properly. I could make a `logic [7:0] dOutTemp = dOut`, then `assign bsOut = dOutTemp[7];`, but this seems clunky.

Comment: You need to shift bits. In C, that would be d0ut >> 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a port expression.

```
module FinalTop (
    input clk,
    output .bsOut(dOut[7])
    );
logic [7:0] dOut;
Shift_Reg shift_reg(.clk, .dOut);
```

Note that `.clk` is equivalent to `.clk(clk)`, etc.